# Seeking a review of Integrated Math I

Tags: algebra, textbooks

I hope I've picked the right group...

My daughter is signed up for Integrated Math II next year in a California school.  She's coming from a french school where the curriculum is different and is worried about being prepared.  I suspect she won't have any problems but am happy to provide her with a review of Integrated Math I if I can find something.

**Does anyone have any recommendations for a review book on the topics covered in Integrated Math I?**  Free is best, but I could order something on Amazon if necessary.  Books or videos would work.

I'm afraid I don't know the topics as the curriculum was different when I was in California schools.  An advanced student entering 9th grade (like my daughter) would have taken Geometry in my day.  My understanding is the Integrated Math curriculum mixes geometry and algebra much more so than the old system.  If so, it's more like the french curriculum!  If I had to guess, I'd say that because of the french curriculum, she's comparatively advanced in geometry, and comparatively weaker in exponents, logs, and long division.  But of course, I really need to see the curriculum.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Dave

Comment: I doubt we can answer here.  Why not contact the school and ask what the topics are in "Integrated Math I" ?  In fact, the topics may vary from one school to another even within California.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment Gerald.  My understanding is that Integrated Math I (and II and III) is pretty much nationwide.  All part of the "common core" curriculum.

Comment: @Dave: Many of us using this site are not based in the US. Even those who are may not know the intricacies of primary education curricula (for example, some work in universities).

Comment: The *names* "Integrated Math I (and II and III) are used nationwide, but I suspect what is actually covered in courses with these names will vary a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **Gerald Edgar** has the best idea: Contact the school (or even check their website, if they are particularly organized) to see what the textbooks are. Perhaps you can even get a hold of the 9th grade Integrated Math *syllabus* used by the school.

To guess at your question: Probably the books are published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt; see [**here**](https://www.hmhco.com/country/us/california/math). You could get a textbook in advance, or look for previews online, or check to see if there are videos of math teachers going through these HMH texts on YouTube; but I would not do any of this without first contacting the school simply to ask, again, *what text do students in [whatever class] use*?

(Side-note: This is not an endorsement of the HMH texts, which I have never used.)

You write in a comment that it is:

> All part of the "common core" curriculum.

But Common Core is a set of Standards, and different places in the United States have created different curricula to tackle them. For example, there are quite a number of helpful resources (in my opinion) found through the $\text{engage}^\text{ny}$ site on *their* Common Core Curriculum; see [**here**](https://www.engageny.org/common-core-curriculum) for links to both the English Language Arts (ELA) and Mathematics materials.

If you have ever read the actual Standards (if not, [**here**](http://www.corestandards.org/Math/) they are for Mathematics) then you will see that they are broken down by grade before high school, and topic (or strand) thereafter. And so the New York link has Pre-K, K, and Grades 1-8; but, subsequently: Algebra, Geometry, Algebra II, and Precalculus/Advanced Topics. So, nothing that is specifically designated as *integrated*.

You may also be interested in the NYC course overviews; see [**here**](https://www.engageny.org/resource/grades-9-12-mathematics-curriculum-map-and-course-overviews). Again, this is all New York based although I recognize your question is about California; still, maybe it is of general interest if you have not looked through Common Core before (and maybe contrasting this with what you find in CA could be of interest). As an example of what is covered in NY, below is an excerpt of their **curriculum map** from *A Story of Functions Curriculum Map and Overview 9-12* (p. 4). Click through for a larger image.

[image]

**Summary:** You could review the topics by directly purchasing an HMH Integrated Math 1 textbook; you could review the topics by looking through the Common Core State Standards for Mathematics to see what is being covered; or you could review the topics by going through the free materials available through the $\text{engage}^\text{ny}$ website. **If** you ask the prospective school about the materials that they use **and** edit your question with this additional information, **then** perhaps I, or others, can give a more substantive answer about recommendations for review textbooks and resources.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin!  I'll check out the links and information.  Now I just need to convince my daughter to actually review the material.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at this post in the future, I include one link to online book I found myself:

http://grade8im1.blogspot.com/2014/09/textbook-online.html

Comment: **FWIW:** This is a CME textbook, published by Pearson, which comes out of EDC (Education Development Center) in Waltham, MA. (It is not so much an "online book" as an uploaded copy of their text; see p. 2 of the front matter...)